# Correct way to handle PHP 7 return types

Tags: php, oop, php-7

I'm busy creating an application and i want to use the PHP 7 return types. Now I read on php.net that it was a design decision that it is not allowed to return `null` when a return type is defined.

What is the correct way too handle this?

One option is a try...catch block:

```
public function getMyObject() : MyObject
{ 
     return null;
}

try
{
    getMyObject();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    //Catch the exception
}
```

I don't have a good feeling about this, because my code will be a huge try...catch block since I need to write a try...catch block for every method that returns an object.

The [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) is a good solution for this, but I don't like the idea to create a `NullObject` for each object in my application. 
Is there correct way to do this?

Comment: return `false`? Simple datatype and still clear that it failed to init the object.

Comment: The void return type was accepted for php 7.1. So it will come in the future.

Comment: The sane solution would be to make sure `getMyObject` returns the actual object. It kinda looks like your object can be in an invalid state which is suboptimal. But without knowing anything about your code it's hard to guess.

Comment: the `void` return type is unrelated to this case

Comment: I don't really get the question, but regardless of what it might be: You should never casually catch `Error` exceptions. Unless you have some very special circumstance, your application should catch these only in one place: The top-level exception handler. I think what you're looking for here is to simply leave off the type annotation. That's still allowed. And if your return is "object or null" then that's what you should do (until such a time as we introduce nullable types).

Comment: Your code needs to be like this to catch the `TypeError` exception: https://gist.github.com/ggirtsou/ee09a5a053e0d17e8caa ```catch Exception``` is executed only in PHP 5.x, [will not be reached in PHP 7](https://trowski.com/2015/06/24/throwable-exceptions-and-errors-in-php7/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't have a good feeling about this, because my code will be a huge try/catch block since I need to write a try / catch block for every method that returns an object.

The alternative (with your code) would be to always check the returned value for `null` to not get errors from using `null` as an object.

Using exceptions is more expressive and makes bugs visible early, which is a good thing. So either make sure that your method always returns an object or throw an exception if it cannot fulfil its contract. Otherwise the return type has no real value.

Comment: It makes sence what you are saying. Maybe it's a habituation to avoid the try/catch blocks, but I think this is a good moment to accept the behaviour and use the benifits of it.

Comment: In case a Null object doesn't make sense (which is often the case), it makes sense to add a second method `hasMyObject()`, which you can check prior to actually getting it. That's the most explicit approach.

Answer (score 29):

If your code expects to return an instance of a class, in this case `MyObject`, but it does not, then that is indeed an exception and should be handled as such.

However, you should throw this exception yourself.

```
public function getMyObject() : MyObject
{
    throw new MyCustomException("Cannot get my object");
}
```

Then you can catch that specific exception and proceed accordingly.

Comment: is there any way to have array of specific objects: something like `public function getMyObject() : Array[MyObject]` ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Option` data type.

It's a type that has `Something` or `Nothing` as a wrapped value.

You can find more elaborate description [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) and one of the open implementations in PHP [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/php-option)

PS please don't use exceptions, out parameters or additional methods for that kind of logic, it's a wrong tool for the job.

Comment: This looks like Haskell [Maybe data type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) and must be part of the [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.spl.php).

Comment: Or `Option` in Rust (which is set to `Some(value)` or `None`) but PHP doesn't have anything like this in SPL. Also the performance of creating a new object in PHP is poor enough that using a runtime object to emulate this in PHP is a bit wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possable currently, though as mentioned there are RFC's that might address the issue for future versions.

As of now, your options are:

1.Drop the return type from your method signature:

```
public function getMyObject()
{ 
     return null;
}
```

2.Throw and catch an exception (as per @NiettheDarkAbsol's answer):

```
public function getMyObject() : MyObject
{
    throw new MyCustomException("Cannot get my object");
}
```

3.Refactor to two methods:

```
private $myObject;
//TODO think of a better method name
public function canGetMyObject() : bool
{
    $this->myObject = new myObject();
    return true;
}

public function getMyObject() : MyObject
{
    if(!$this->myObject){
        throw new MyCustomException("Cannot get my object");
    }
    return $this->myObject;
}
```

Calling code:

```
if($cls->canGetMyObject()){
    $myObject  = $cls->getMyObject();
}
```

4.Use a bool return type and an out parameter:

```
public function tryGetMyObject(&$out) : bool
{
    $out = new myObject();
    return true;
}
```

Calling code:

```
$myObject = null;

if($cls->tryGetMyObject($myObject)){      
    $myObject->someMethod(); //$myObject is an instance of MyObject class
}
```

The 3rd and 4th options are only really worth considering in cases where a null return is expected and frequant, such that the overhead of exceptions is a factor.
Probably you will find this doesnt actually apply all that often and exceptions are the way forward

Comment: From the different answers I taste that the best way to go is throwing custom exceptions. I'll try that and hope the overhead will be worth the advantages!

Comment: Yes, thats probably true, the other options above are only really for specific circumstances, and some would argue exceptions are the best solution. Note i added a forth method you may prefer over the 3rd

Answer (score 2):

As of PHP7.1, you can use nullable return types:

```
public function getMyObject(): ?MyObject {
  return null;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Comment: And with PHP 8 you can write `: Myobject|false` if you don't want to return `null` instead of `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask for the same. I don't see much point for this.

If I have the following sample code to find User by name:

```
<?php

class User
{
    protected $name;

    /**
     * User constructor.
     *
     * @param $name
     */
    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}


function findUserByName(string $name, array $users) : User {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->getName() == $name) {
            return $user;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


$users = [
    new User('John'), new User('Daniel')
];

$user = findUserByName('John', $users);

echo $user->getName()."\n";

$user2 = findUserByName('Micheal', $users);
```

I would like to tell Php I can get either User or null. Now I need to wrap it always in try catch block and I don't see much sense to declare return type in this case. On the other hand If my `findUserByName` function would be complex I could return accidentally for example user name instead of full user object so I would like to have return type defined.

I think much more reasonable would be defining multiple return types for functions. Sometimes you create function that return one object or array of objects, and it would be nice to define, this function should return for example `User` or array of users: `User[]`.

In OP case (and also mine) we could then declare return type as `User, null` and it would solve the problem.