# Symfony3 and PHP 7 return type decleration for Doctrine Repository methods

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony, php-7

I really like PHP's return type declarations, and I want to use it on Symfony 3.

All controller methods should return a `Response` object, no problem there. But in Doctrine repositories though, Doctrine might return an Entity object, or `null`.

#### Consider this example:

- You have created a simple `Post` entity.
- You have created a custom `findByName` method in `PostRepository`:

**PostRepository.php**

```
public function findByName($name) : Post
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.name = :name')
        ->setParameter('name', $name);

    $post = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

    return (null === $post) ? new Post() : $post;
}
```

You call this method from a controller, like this:

**DefaultController.php**

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post');

    try {
        $post = $repository->findByName('test');
    } catch (\TypeError $e) {
        $post = new Post();
    }

    return new Response(dump($post));
}
```

*I am aware trying to catch exception won't execute because `findByName()` always returns a Post object.*

My question is, where should we handle the exception? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268063/correct-way-to-handle-php-7-return-types/34268572#34268572), it is better to throw an exception. Should we ensure repository method does not throw an exception at all by using this:

```
$post = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();

return (null === $post) ? new Post() : $post;
```

or let PHP throw a TypeError exception and let controller handle it?

Doctrine, throws exceptions for `getOneOrNullResult()` and `getSingleResult()` methods as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354031/1294631).

If this scenario doesn't make sense because it's better to let your controller handle the exception and return a "not found" page because post doesn't exist like this:

```
return $this->createNotFoundException();
```

#### Scenario #2

`Post` exists in the database, and another repository method is called, `getApprovedComments()`, no comments are returned, we're expecting an `ArrayCollection` but we get an `array`. This will throw PHP's `TypeError` exception.

I think code is going to be full of try/catch blocks. Is it ok to handle this kind of exceptions at a higher level to have less try/catch blocks in code?

At a second thought this is not the best solution, because code should be flexible enough to catch every `TypeError` exception and take proper action on how to render the page.

Comment: Whatever else you may do, you absolutely shouldn't be catching TypeErrors, or any other Errors for that matter. If an Error occurs it implies a programming mistake that must be resolved by avoiding the condition that lead to the Error being thrown. That's pretty much the purpose of the Error vs Exception distinction. You should only ever catch Errors in your top-level exception handler, or if you're in some really specific, really special situation.

Comment: @NikiC thanks, but that means user will see an exception on the frontend of the site because a database query did not return expected results? If errors are hidden, user will simply see an error page? To sum up, I need to make sure method always return correct type no matter what. Can you provide any official sources to support your statement, please?

Comment: You should be aware that Symfony controller action methods are not required to return a response object and often don't.  Just my opinion but I think you may be over-complicating things.

Comment: @Cerad according to [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) "A controller is a PHP callable you create that takes information from the HTTP request and creates and returns an HTTP response (as a Symfony Response object).". If controller action method does not return a `Response` object, a `LogicException` exception is thrown with this message: "_The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?_"

Comment: Looks like the docs need a bit of tweaking.  The request handler checks the results of calling a controller action.  If it is not a response then it dispatches the results to a listener which in turn can generate a response.  This is how, for example, the sensio @template directive works: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html.  As you can see, the controller returns an array.  This by the way is one reason that I usually recommend building a few apps before trying to adjust things too much.

Comment: I see what you mean. I forgot the ```@Template``` annotation returns an ```array```. In that case that particular controller action method would have an ```array``` as return type declaration.