# PHP 7 return type hinting

Tags: php, oop, php-7

There are already a lot of questions according to PHP 7 return type hinting and why it is not possible to return null if a class was defined as a return type. Like this one: [Correct way to handle PHP 7 return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268063/correct-way-to-handle-php-7-return-types). 
The answers usually say that it is not a problem as if a function should return a class then returning null is probably an exception anyway. 
Maybe I have missed somthing but I don't really understand why. For example let's see a simple user class:

```
class User
{
    private $username;  // mandatory
    private $password;  // mandatory
    private $realName;  // optional
    private $address;   // optional

    public function getUsername() : string {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(string $username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword() : string {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getRealName() : string {
        return $this->realName;
    }

    public function setRealName(string $realName = null) {
        $this->realName = $realName;
    }

    public function getAddress() : Address {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(Address $address = null) {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

}
```

In our application it is totally legal to have a user without a realName and/or without an address. I even can set the realName and address fields to null - even if the solution above is not optimal. And in our profile page I want to display a hint if the address is null (empty).

But this is only 1 example. Our application has more than 100 database tables and corresponding PHP classes and almost all of them have optional fields. Always writing a try catch block instead of simply checking null to handle optional fields seems to be a bit suboptimal for me.

So what is a good solution for the example above?

Comment: You could just initialize the variables to empty default values (Like strings to '' and Address to an address object with empty/invalid/default values. You could also use your classes calling them from a wrapper that would catch the exception if you are returning a null.

Comment: I don't think getAddress().getCity === '' is better than simply check getAddress() == null. Besides this the check can be complicated. As for example if the zipcode is optional then a new developer can write a code: getAddress().getZip() === '' and he/she thinks the address is missing, however only the zipcode is missing.

Comment: In your example, what would you expect the calling code's behaviour to be when it calls `getRealName()` when `$this->realName` is null? Does it need to test the value and handle it if it's null? If so: your class should be doing that. If you are leveraging that null strings are kinda treated like empty strings for a lot of string operations, you probably ought to actually default it to an empty string, not a null. Most situations can be resolved like this. That said, I think PHP is being inappropriately opinionated in its enforcing of this.

Comment: Could do something `Address::empty()` to indicate an empty address instead of using null. Though I'd personally just not type-hint optional fields.

Comment: @AdamCameron The caller class (ie. UserPrifile) should handle the situation. In this case for example on the registration form only username and password fields are present. So realName should remain null as later on a profile page I can show a hint to fill out the real name. However if the user don't want it we will simple save an empty string so next time we don't bother the user. So null and an empty string results a different logic.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your object doesn't follow the OOP rules.

First, [getters and setters are evil](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html) because they expose the internal structure of the object. You just introduce the infinite possibility to depend on the internal user object structure for the rest of your system. While the purpose of the object is to hide the implementation details and provide the interface to manipulate this hidden data.

And [null is evil](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html) (or [a billion dollar mistake](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare)) because it makes the code much less reliable.
It introduces the special case (null return value) and it is necessary to handle this special case in the code with uses your object.
The worse thing is that if you forget to handle this "null" special case (or if you don't know that there is a special case), you will not get the error immediately.
So you will get the hidden error which can be very time-consuming to find and fix.

Practically, I see following options (in all cases - remove the getters):

Option 1) Get the snapshot of the profile data in some unified form

```
$user->getProfileData() {
    return [
        'username': $this->username,
        'realName': $this->realName ? $this->realName : '',
        'address': $this->address ? $this->address : 'Not specified'
        ...
    ];
}
```

This is still a kind of a getter, but you transform all the data into the unified form (strings). Even if you have some integer of float fields (like age or height) in your database, you would still return strings here, so the rest of your system doesn't depend on actual internals of the object.

The empty string (or special value like "not specified") for optional fields also acts as a kind of "null object". It's also possible to wrap the returned values into small fields-objects and actually use the null object pattern for optional fields.

In the code which uses the class you should not deal with the special "null" case, you just loop over fields and show strings (including those which are empty).

Option 2) Make the object itself responsible for the presentation

```
$user->showProfile($profileView) {
    $profileView->addLabel('First Name');
    $profileView->addString($this->username);
    ...
}
```

Here you keep the internal details inside the object, but now it does too much, so someone could say it now violates the [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Option 3) Create special object responsible for the presentation

```
$userPresentation = $user->createPresentation()
// internally it will return new UserPresentation($this->username, this->realName, $this->address, ...);
// now display it - generate the template and insert it into the view
<? echo $userPresentation->getHtml(); ?>
```

Here you move the presentation logic into the separate object. The user object and it's presentation are tightly coupled, but the rest of the system now knows nothing (and has no chance to know) about the user object internals.

Comment: Very detailed answer, however I think in case of a simple entity class all of the 3 options violate SRP. I don't want to create always a new getter and a new class for a subset of User properties depending on what a caller class requires. And of course I don't want any presentation logic in my entity class.

Comment: @Vmxes the problem with your current implementation is that it violates one of the basic OOP principles - encapsulation. Although you define your fields as `private`, you then open these fields to the world with getters and setters. And you return nulls, so you then have to check for special cases all around the code. Once you start thinking on how to get rid of these flaws and use other approaches, you'll see that the rest of your code will also become more simple and unified. My examples are just some options that came in mind, check also the articles I linked.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently embraced the idea that ***null*** means there's a problem, so that I know that when I see it, it means something went wrong.

In these situations I tend to use the [Null Object design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).
So, to handle the address, you would create something like:

```
class NullAddress implements AddressInterface { }
```

The `Address` class would also need to implement `AddressInterface`.
Then, `getAddress()` would look like:

```
public function getAddress(): AddressInterface {
    return $this->address ?? new NullAddress();
}
```

A function calling `getAddress()` can then check for a null value by:

```
if ($user->getAddress() instanceof NullAddress) {
    // Implement result of empty address here.
}
```

For handling strings, an returning empty string has served me well so far. I just use `empty()` to check it.